# Software to conduct surveys and offer recommendations based on results

Tags: web-apps, charts, survey

I would like to find a web app that lets me conduct surveys, create charts from the results, and display them to my users immediately, along with recommended actions.

So, for example, if one of my questions was about how many carrots someone ate on a monthly basis, the corresponding chart displayed after the survey might look something like this:

[image: carrots eaten chart]

And the recommendation would be something like:

> Our recommendation: In general, you eat enough carrots, but you could definitely try to eat more carrots toward the beginning of the year.

Can you think of a web app that could do this? Or would this require a custom project?

Answer (score 1):

Giving any recommendations would very likely need a complex project (on custom or purchased engine) because recommendations fall into an area of [Expert systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system).

For example, regarding your carrot recommendation example above: would you really give that recommendation to anyone without knowing their clinical conditions etc.?

I suggest closing this question and finding/opening question only for the first part ("software to conduct surveys").

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these 2 demo samples:

- [Example 1](http://drupal.placeto.be/charts/examples).
- [Example 2](http://drupal.placeto.be/charts/examples/views).

Even though these samples are not about **carrots**, it should be clear that they are somehow similar to what you're asking for.

Here is what's required to create these example charts:

- [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) (version 7) and "contributed" module "[Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts)" (GPL license, and free of charge).
- An internet connection to use [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) as the charting engine (free of charge).
- Knowledge of how to use these Drupal for creating such charts that match your exact needs.

About the "recommendation" to be added to such charts: probably using the contributed [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module you could get pretty far also ... think of it as a macro language available in Drupal, using:

- Events (triggers), eg: "when visiting a page".
- Conditions, eg: "if some data comparison returns *true*".
- Actions, eg: "display an appropriate message (and/or send an eMail)".

Disclosure: I'm the (co-) maintainer of [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts).